# add contacts to Gtalk using Pidgin

Tags: gmail, pidgin, google-talk

I'm using Pidgin for Instant Messenger,it connects to multiple accounts-as Ebuddy-.
 Log-in with Google Account "Gmail"
Then I'd like to add my friends E-mail as they are different (Gmail,Hotmail,Yahoo,....)
but seems no way to add else Gmail contacts !,when adding Yahoo contact -for example-it appears in my contacts with signal beside said:"Not Authorized" and my friend doesn't receive any invitation !  
Is there any guide how to add contacts ! any help !?
Is it problem with Gmail server ! 

Thanks in Advance :).